# Print list with space rather comma

Tags: list, haskell

I have a problem with a function of Haskell: after converting a tree into a list I need to print it with items separated by a space instead of a comma.

For example:

```
data Tree a = Empty | Branch a (Tree a) (Tree a)
              deriving (Show, Eq)

tree4 = Branch 1 (Branch 2 Empty (Branch 4 Empty Empty)) (Branch 2 Empty Empty)

leaves :: Tree a -> [a]
leaves  Empty                 = []
leaves (Branch a Empty Empty) = [a]
leaves (Branch a left  right) = leaves left ++ leaves right
```

The result is:

```
*Main> leaves tree4 
[4,2]
```

but I would like that the result is:

```
*Main> leaves tree4 
 4 2
*Main>
```

How can I do this?

I thought, first, to override the class show in this way:

```
newtype SimpleRecords = SimpleRecords [Integer]

instance Show SimpleRecords where
  show (SimpleRecords []) = ""
  show (SimpleRecords (x:xs)) = show x ++ " " ++ show (SimpleRecords xs)
```

but I cannot integrate it in my function.

Comment: Why not have `leaves :: Tree a -> String`? Or write a function `listToString :: [a] -> String` (if such a function not exists already) and call `listToString $ leaves tree4`.

Comment: Try `unwords $ map show $ leaves tree4`. Or you can make `Show a => Show (Tree a)` instance where `show = unwords . map show . leaves`, which will do exactly what you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
data Tree a = Empty | Branch a (Tree a) (Tree a)
              deriving (Show, Eq)

tree4 = Branch 1 (Branch 2 Empty (Branch 4 Empty Empty)) (Branch 2 Empty Empty)

leaves :: Tree a -> SimpleRecords a
leaves  Empty                 = SimpleRecords []
leaves (Branch a Empty Empty) = SimpleRecords  [a]
leaves (Branch a left  right) = SimpleRecords (left' ++ right')
    where
        SimpleRecords left' = leaves left
        SimpleRecords right'= leaves right

newtype SimpleRecords a = SimpleRecords [a]

instance (Show a)=>Show (SimpleRecords a) where
  show (SimpleRecords []) = ""
  show (SimpleRecords (x:xs)) = show x ++ " " ++ show (SimpleRecords xs)
```

Answer (score 3):

You have done almost everything. But to make `SimpleRecords` compatible with `Tree` you have to get rid of `Integer` and make it polymorphic.

```
newtype SimpleRecords a = SimpleRecords [a]

instance Show a => Show (SimpleRecords a) where
    show (SimpleRecords []) = ""
    show (SimpleRecords (x:xs)) = show x ++ " " ++ show (SimpleRecords xs)
```

Now change your `leaves` function to emit `SimpleRecords`:

```
leaves :: Tree a -> SimpleRecords a
leaves xs = SimpleRecords $ aux xs
    where
      aux  Empty                 = []
      aux (Branch a Empty Empty) = [a]
      aux (Branch a left  right) = aux left ++ aux right
```

Demo in `ghci`:

```
λ> leaves tree4 
4 2
```